# .xls & .xlsx Download file crash using apache camel

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel, xls, xlsx

i need to upload xls and xlsx file in ftp using apache camel.
i have asimple code to upload download file in ftp but it cat'n work for xls &xlsx file.
file is crash during processing.

what i need to do for this any can help me.
thank you for your response.

```
package ftp;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class File_download_local_system {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        //final long delay = 60 * 60 *2000L;
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                 from("file:D:\\uttam\\files?fileName=test.xls&idempotent=true&noop=true").to("ftp://cuboidology8@127.1.2.3:21/src?password=cuboidology8");
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

Crash means that when I download and open the file, it gives me an
error like: **Excel found unreadable content in file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only keep this application running for 1.5 seconds. That is not a long time. And what do you mean by crash? Your question lacks such details.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the attribute "binary=true" as this is an Excel File which you would like to transfer to the FTP.